# How to figure out a moon phase for July 1937

Tags: moon-phases

I would like to know how to figure out the moon's phase for July 4, 1937 at 9:34 pm. Thank you.

Comment: Is this for some astrology cobblers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I calculate moon phase and height?](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/914/how-can-i-calculate-moon-phase-and-height)

Answer (score 3):

There exist websites that do exactly that for you, like [Phases of the Moon](http://aa.usno.navy.mil/data/docs/MoonPhase.php) . For your parameters, the phase was between the last quarter and new Moon, so just a tiny edge.

Visualized:

[image]